# Are two machine learning models preferable to one when predicting a time series with several zeros?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction

I have a data series of positive integers. The majority of values are zero, but occasionally the values can be quite high. The task is to predict the following value given a set of features.

Let's say I have two approaches:

A) I train a machine learning model, e.g. random forest, using all features and all output values (with a training and test set of course). I then run it to predict future values.

B) I create two models. The first model is a classifier, determining if the following value is zero or non-zero. The second is a model similar to the one used in approach A, but trained with only non-zero output values. During prediction, I start by running the first model. Only if this model indicates that the output will be non-zero, I run the second model to predict the actual value.

My questions are:

- Are any of the two approaches likely to be better than the other? If yes, which and why?
- Does it depend on which machine learning model I use? Can it for example be better with approach A using random forest, but B if using neural networks?

I'd be very happy if you could help me with this. Thank you,

/Anders

Comment: There’s a precedent for the second approach in statistics. Look up zero inflated negative binomial regression. When it comes to an ML based approach I don’t have an opinion. Generally with ML the strategy is to try different things and see what works best. Also, consider optimal performance. How important is it to correctly predict zeroes, vs overall good accuracy? There will probably be trade offs between those outcomes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it

Comment: What do the zeros *mean?* Often such datasets represent *point events* where from one random time to another, something happens and some quantitative property of it is observed.  Think of occasional sales of a product, for instance, where the number of units of that product is recorded along with the time of each sale. In that case the zeros are purely a database artifact--they aren't actually data and need to be treated accordingly in the analysis.